# Creating a BST in Racket

Tags: data-structures, lisp, scheme, racket, binary-search-tree

I am currently trying to write a function that finds a value in racket using DrRacket. With some help I came up with this below. However I need someone to explain to me what the difference is between `cadr` and `caddr`? Also in DrRacket how would I create a BST? Is it similar to making a list?

```
(define (find-val bst elt)
    (cond ((null? bst) #f)
          ((< elt (car bst))
           (find-val (cadr bst) elt))
          ((> elt (car bst))
           (bst (caddr bst) elt))
          ((equal? elt (car bst))
           #t)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of your question,

```
(cadr x)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(car (cdr x))
```

and

```
(caddr x)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(car (cdr (cdr x)))
```

Did you notice the pattern? each `d` between the `c` and `r` is a shorthand for a `cdr`, and each `a` between the `c` and `r` is a shorthand for a `car`, in left-to-right order.

Regarding the second part of your question, there's a very detailed explanation of how to represent a BST in the book [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), section [§2.3.3](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.3) under the title *sets as binary trees*. There you'll find the required procedures for creating and manipulating a tree.

Answer (score 0):

In Racket, we can use **struct** to define the shape of structured values.  For example:

```
(struct person (name age))
```

defines a `person` structure.  It allows us to create 2-field structured values, such as:

```
(define p1 (person "danny" 33))
(define p2 (person "richie" 31))
```

We can access individual fields of a structured value by using its selector functions.

```
;; p: person -> void
(define (say-hi p)
  (printf "hi, my name is ~a, and I am ~a years old\n"
          (person-name p)
          (person-age p)))

(say-hi p1)
(say-hi p2)
```

There are other ways of creating structured values, such as using plain list structure.  But using **struct** is preferable for most applications in Racket.  Here are several reasons why:

1. Access to a field in a **struct** is fast--a single dereference.  In list representation, field access involves walking the list structure, which is somewhat more expensive.
2. The type checks in **struct** selectors can more quickly detect mistakes in passing the wrong kind of data around, and produce the appropriate error messages.

Creating a binary search tree, then, involves defining a structure to represent the individual nodes of the tree.  It also requires following fairly rigorous rules during construction, since the nodes are ordered in a peculiar way to make searching through the structure potentially faster than sequential lists.

An algorithms textbook should go over some of the potential rulesets we can follow to create BSTs that guarantee good balance among the nodes.  These include things like [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which can have peculiar rules on how to maintain the structure of the tree as inserts push values into the tree.  There is nothing really *Racket* specific to how it happens: it's just the general requirements we need to follow to make the balance work out.

Matt Might has written a [very nice article on red-black trees](http://matt.might.net/articles/red-black-delete/) implemented in Racket.